# Match Regex from source-code file and save to list/dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I want to match regex from a typescript file I have and add every match to a list. My ultimate goal is to make a dataframe out of it.
The typescript file that looks like this:

```
 ApplicationStarted: {
            gaData: {
                eventCategory: AnalyticsConstants.EventCategories.UserInteraction,
                eventAction: 'Application Started',
                eventLabel: ''
            },
            eventName: 'Application Started',
            description: 'Raised when the Fiddler Everywhere application is started'
        },

        InstanceStarted: {
            gaData: {
                eventCategory: AnalyticsConstants.EventCategories.UserInteraction,
                eventAction: 'New Instance Started',
                eventLabel: 'Instance started for path {0}'
            },
            eventName: 'New Instance Started',
            description: 'Raised when a new instance of the Angular application is started - this could be due to opening a new window or trying it in browser.'
        },
```

The regex matches I want are `(?<=eventAction:).*` and `(?<=description:).*.`
Can I use a dictionary for this? Idk how to.

my final output needs to be a dataframe that looks like this:

```
eventAction                    description
Application Started        Raised when the Fiddler Everywhere application is started
New Instance Started       Raised when a new instance of the Angular application is started ..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the provided regex patterns, the extracted text can be loaded into a pandas dataframe:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

text = """
ApplicationStarted: {
            gaData: {
                eventCategory: AnalyticsConstants.EventCategories.UserInteraction,
                eventAction: 'Application Started',
                eventLabel: ''
            },
            eventName: 'Application Started',
            description: 'Raised when the Fiddler Everywhere application is started'
        },

        InstanceStarted: {
            gaData: {
                eventCategory: AnalyticsConstants.EventCategories.UserInteraction,
                eventAction: 'New Instance Started',
                eventLabel: 'Instance started for path {0}'
            },
            eventName: 'New Instance Started',
            description: 'Raised when a new instance of the Angular application is started - this could be due to opening a new window or trying it in browser.'
        },
"""
regex_1 = re.compile(r"(?<=eventAction:).*")
regex_2 = re.compile(r"(?<=description:).*.")
res_1 = re.findall(regex_1, text)
res_1 = [res.strip(' ').strip('\'').strip(',')[:-1] for res in res_1]
res_2 = re.findall(regex_2, text)
res_2 = [res.strip(' ').strip('\'') for res in res_2]
cols = ['eventAction', 'description']
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(res_1, res_2),
                  columns=cols
                  )
print(df)
```

Produces:

```
            eventAction                                        description
0   Application Started  Raised when the Fiddler Everywhere application...
1  New Instance Started  Raised when a new instance of the Angular appl...
```

See the whole df by setting the max column width (the value 150 works for this data):

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', 150)
print(df)
```

And we get:

```
            eventAction                                                                                                                            description
0   Application Started                                                                              Raised when the Fiddler Everywhere application is started
1  New Instance Started  Raised when a new instance of the Angular application is started - this could be due to opening a new window or trying it in browser.
```